# Eclipse how to refactor Javadoc source comment?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, refactoring, javadoc

After making some changes to a method, I find it utterly annoying to have to manually re-factor the Javadoc source comment immediately preceding the method call.  Is there a way to get Eclipse to automatically do this for you?

Comment: I wonder how exactly you refactor something that's not code. On a more serious note: what specifically do you mean by "some changes" that you want to be performed automatically?

Comment: Say I drop or add an argument.. or change a return type.. not hard to image what kind of changes you can make to a method that would consider the javadoc "out of date" and need to be "refactored"..

Comment: ... it is harder though to imagine the changes where eclipse could automatically write a meaningful comment. Sure, eclipse could add a placeholder for a new parameter, but the programmer will still have to write the description himself.

Comment: It's also possible you have something else than a signature change in mind, and it's better to ask for clarification than to make assumptions. (As a corollary, it's also better to be clear in the first place rather than expect people to be thinking what you're thinking.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the only way to let eclipse automatically update your Java Doc based on the changes that you have done in the method signature is do the changes from the eclipse own menu function :

```
Refactor ---> Change Method Signature
```

If you change a the method signature from here you get automatically updated the JAvadoc comment, otherwise you have to delete the entire javadoc comment and recreate it typing :

```
/** + <HIT ENTER>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, pressing Alt-Shift-J again will regenerate the javadocs. That's how I usually do it.

Answer (score 2):

Google's CodePro Analytix plugin for Eclipse will [do that](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/javadoc.html) for you.